# How do I formally prove $\lim_{x \to\infty}f(x+b)-f(x) = 0$?

Tags: limits

This question all stems from me wanting to formally prove the statement that $\lim_{x \to\infty}f(x+b)-f(x)$ should be equal to zero. My reasoning is because x approaches $\infty$, x becomes much greater than b ($x\gg b$), and therefore $x+b \approx x$, making the statement be $\lim_{x \to\infty}f(x) - f(x) = \lim_{x \to\infty} 0 = 0$. However, the trouble is that I need to formally prove the statement that $x\gg b$ implies $x+b \approx x$ (aka. a more rigorous proof) which I don't know how to do. My question is how to formally prove that $x\gg b$ implies $x+b \approx x$ or, if that core assumption is wrong, how to formally prove that $\lim_{x \to\infty}f(x+b)-f(x) = 0$ because I'm like 99% sure that it's true.

Comment: What if $f(x)=7x$, for example?

Comment: I guess the logic breaks down for $f(x) = 7x$, because the limit is equal to $7b$. The original function I had was $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and I guessed I generalized it wrong to all $f(x)$. However the question still stands, modified, in that how do I prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x+b)-f(x)$ converges (because that's kind of all I need and I'm still sure it does converge) and, as a bonus question if someone wants to go above and beyond, what part of my logic above failed to make the statement untrue for a function like $f(x) = 7x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim is false, however there is still something interesting here, and it is the (or one of the) proper and formal definition of your $\approx$ symbol.

First of all, your initial claim is false, because although $x+b$ gets *relatively* closer to $x$ as $x \to +\infty$, it does not mean that there images by $f$ do the same. For example, under $f : x \mapsto x$, we always have $f(x+b) - f(x) = x+b - x = b$.

Nonetheless, it is still a good idea to learn how to properly work with this intuition of "things becoming more or less the same", like $x+b \approx x$ if $x \to +\infty$. One way to define this formally is to the notion of [asymptotic equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis).

Let $f, g$ functions defined in a neighbourhood of $a \in \mathbb R \cup \{\pm \infty\}$. Then, we say that $f$ and $g$ are *asymptotically equivalent* in the neighbourooh of $a$ if $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \xrightarrow[x \to a]{} 1$ (there is a way to define this if $g(x) \xrightarrow[x\to a]{} 0$ but it requires some extra-definitions which are not useful here).

For example, $x^2 + x$ and $x^2$ are equivalent as $x \to +\infty$ because $\frac{x^2+x}{x^2} \to 1$.

What is interesting is that this property of being equivalent can be composed with several operations (for example, the product or the quotient ...). However, applying a function - even a continuous one - to equivalent functions does not necessarily yield equivalent functions, as we saw.

Comment: This definition of things being asymptotically equivalent is really helpful and is a good formal and rigorous definition for my intuitive idea of $\approx$. A follow up question then, assuming two functions ($f(x)$ and $g(x)$) are asymptotically equivalent, can we say anything about the limits involving them which approach infinity such as $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) - g(x)$?

Comment: @LogarithmicEage $f$ and $g$ could be asymptotically equivalent but the limit of their difference $f(x)-g(x)$ need not tend to zero as $x$ gets large. Take, for example, $f(x)=x+\sin(x)$ and $g(x)=x$

Comment: I understand that, but I'm just wondering if there is anything we can say about the limit such as can we guarantee that it converges

Comment: @LogarithmicEagle we cannot guarantee the limit of the difference converges at all. In my example $f(x)-g(x)=\sin(x)$ which doesn't converge as $x$ goes to $\infty$. We could replace $\sin$ with any bounded but wildly oscillating function and get an even more extreme example of this.

Comment: In that case, can we make a definitive statement that the limit doesn't diverge (which means that it either converges or the limit doesn't exist, which satisfies your example because the limit of $\sin$ doesn't exist as it approaches $\infty$ which implies that it doesn't diverge)?

Comment: Equivalents do help out, but one needs to learn their own set of laws and restrictions. It is better to just remember the more fundamental limit laws. If a thing is not allowed by limit laws, don't do that.